# App signature changes after installing app on the system partition

Tags: android, signing

I'm developing an app for specific tablets that should be updated via our custom server (just checking the json with the version and if that version is bigger then current one - we download new apk and install it.
And facing some strange signing behavior.

I sign an app with the release key and after install it on the device - everything works properly.
BUT
when tablets' manufacturer installs that signed apk as system app - then somehow signing certificate of the app changes and I cannot update it (because certificates are different according to the console).

I tried to log hashes of the certificates and what i've received:

- simple installation mode:

  - current: 1925650013
  - next version: 1925650013
- app installed as system

  - current: -1314815697
  - next version: 1925650013

looks like it became "debug" key, and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already contains the answer: `when tablets' manufacturer installs that signed apk as system app`.

System apps (in the original meaning) are granted the system permission and for getting this permission the app has to be signed with the system manufacturer's key.

If your app does not require system permissions I assume this is a misunderstanding between you and the tablet manufacturer - in such a case you only want to have your app pre-installed on the system partition. Most users call such an app "system app" but actually it is just a regular app on the system partition.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your attention :)

Yeah, probably they have just installed it on the system partition as you said.
But have you any thoughts what can change the signing certificate of the app?
Because except enabling wifi and bluetooth, our app doesn't do anything with the native side, so we can easily count it as pre-installed. and All we need is to be able to update it :)